# Aspose.Cell error in .Net Standard 2.0 Library

Tags: c#, .net-standard, aspose, aspose-cells

Could not load file or assembly ‘Aspose.Cells, Version=19.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56’ or one of its dependencies. The located assembly’s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am getting above in .Net Standard 2.0 type library. I have added Aspose.Cell nuget package reference to the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add Aspose.Cells, Version=19.7.0.0 reference in hosting project also instead of only class library projects.

Answer (score 0):

You may please add System.Drawing.Common library from the NuGet package manager to resolve the issue. In some cases you may also require System.Text.Encoding. Please note, while using NuGet package manager, it may automatically fetch all the required dependencies for Aspose.Cells, it look to me not in your case though. So, you should manually install System.Drawing.common v4.5.1 after installing Aspose.Cells 19.7.0.

To check the dependencies on Nuget repos page of Aspose.Cells v19.7.0, you may click on "Dependencies" node and may confirm the following depenencies for .NET Standard 2.0:
System.Drawing.Common (>= 4.5.1)
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages (>= 4.4.0)

Hope, this helps.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.